# Qual o código de erro do HTTP devo usar?

Tags: xml, tomcat, java

O projeto tem uma pagina de login com dois campos um de email e outro que é a sua senha!
Tenho uma aplicação javaweb e no descritor de implantação tenho algumas paginas de erro declaradas, que são  relativas aos erros cometidos pelo o usuários, com essas paginas de erro eu os encaminho para paginas personalizadas informando o o respectivo problema!
Esse dois são famosos:

```
    <error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/ErroPaginaNaoEncontrada.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
    <error-page>
        <error-code>500</error-code>
        <location>/WEB-INF/ErroLogin.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

O primeiro, 404, pagina não encontrada esta ok.

O segundo,500,erro de login tem  um  pequeno defeito , não sei se é um erro meu, quando o usuário coloca o seu email errado e a senha certa o erro, na aplicação ocorre tudo certo!
Como ele inseriu seu email incorreto o erro é captado pela aplicação e o cliente e encaminhado para uma pagina dizendo que ele colocou o email errado!
Mas se ele coloca o email correto e a senha errada o erro não é capturado pela aplicação, não sei  o que fazer.
Qual o codigo do status que eu devo colocar para capturar exatamente esse erro de senha? ou qual a solução mais viável? Já tentei alguns da linha 400 até 500, mas nada!
Aqui esta meu servlet de Login:

```
public class Login extends HttpServlet {

    private UsuarioDAOInterface usuarioDAO = DAOFactory.createFactory(NomeBanco.DAO_BD).criarUsuarioDAO();

    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        doPost(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

        String email = request.getParameter("email");
        String senha = request.getParameter("senha");


        UsuarioBean usuario = new UsuarioBean();

        usuario = usuarioDAO.selecionarPorEmail(email);
        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        session.setAttribute("usuario", usuario);


        if (usuario.getEmail().equals(email) && usuario.getSenha().equals(senha)) {

            RequestDispatcher dispatcher
                    = request.getRequestDispatcher("Home.jsp");

            dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Você está usando páginas 404 e 500 para informar o usuário que houve um erro na entrada de dados da aplicação?

Comment: @bigown  Isso mesmo! O primeiro caso ele pesquise uma pagina que não existe dentro da aplicação e  segundo pega o erro do login

Comment: OMG. Não faça isto. Estes erros não forma criados para isto. Em caso muito específico eu usaria um erro mais claro que expressasse que o erro é de domínio. Mesmo assim duvido que faria sentido usar isto. Pensaria em algo como 422 ou 428. Mas sinto que até isto é o cominho errado.  Não sei nem se deveria sugerir outro códigos. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: @bigown Valeu cara, cara mas já havia visitado esse site antes

Comment: Isso você trata no recurso chamado, por exemplo, em um Servlet que controla o login. A falta de um atributo na requisição é uma "exceção", não um status. Só lembrando: Você pode usar JS ou até mesmo os atributos de validação do HTML5 para resolver ainda no lado do *client* (e nem fazer a requisição se a senha estiver faltando).

Comment: A única coisa que parece como que você quer é o 401, ou o 403 se o login estiver correto, mas o usuário não tiver permissão para aquele recurso. E mesmo assim, acho meio exagerado emitir um erro HTTP pra isso. 500 é erro de servidor, sinal de algum problema sério. E não deixa de ser verdade que você está com um problema sério emitindo ele :)

Answer (score 1):

Olá, @Pena,

Como como você não entrou em detalhes de como sua aplicação está implementando o login, irei falar apenas de HTTP. 
Quando algum usuário acessa algum recurso que ele não possui devido acesso, o HTTP CODE para isso é o 403.

Você poderia fazer algo parecido com isso:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>403</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/ogin.jsp?msg=Usuário sem direito de acesso</location>
  </error-page>
```

Caso você tenha algum problema na implementação de sua lógica de login, estaremos aqui para tentar auxiliar, basta fazer uma nova pergunta.

Segue o link dos Status Code: http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei o servlet ,brother. Obrigado pela atenção!!